# Can I connect a 3440x1440 display to my late 2013 27" iMac?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt-display

Currently I'm running an external 27"  2560x1440 apple cinema display from the thunderbolt port. I have a second thunderbolt port, so I was wondering if it's possible to also use a thunderbolt enabled 3440x1440 monitor, maybe like the LG 34UM95C. The computer is a late 2013 iMac with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M graphics card.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i7-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-late-2013-specs.html) says your machine can support two external displays up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt, so I think the answer would be no.

Comment: This can't be right. I am currently running two external displays at 4k30 (3840 x 2160 @ 30hz) on my Late 2013 27" iMac with a 780M.